# web api and mvc partials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is the "Partial view" approach still viable when you use web api and mvc?

If so, how would you approach this situation? I assume something like this?

1. request page from mvc
2. call for the partial from mvc (which I assume, contains a template for javascript data binding?)
3. ajax call to web api for the data
4. bind the json data with knockoutjs,Angularjs,.. (which do you recommend?)

but this seems like a slow way of doing things ('cause you always need to make 2 calls). Or should you just use *the old method* and call web api from the mvc action? (this wouldn't require javascript data binding, which I don't mind, I don't have any experience with javascript databinding frameworks yet)

Another possibility is embedding the partial templates on the page itself, but if you're working with a lot of different Partials, doesn't that affect the data? E.g. if you request a list of DTOs and each DTO should be represented in a different view(because of different states). Doesn't this give the client too much power over the data?

If it's not a viable approach anymore, how should I do it then (using the list of objects with different states example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it gives client not to much power over data. When you need you can implement it all even without partials, or "embedd" it as you said.

It doesn't give client to much control and even you can implement your Views in Single Page Application (SPA) concept, when with KnockoutJs or Angular or something else you are giving to client Js more responsiblity and it has it's own "ViewModel". In such situation client becomes data from ASP.NET Web API Service or from your page using ajax. In both cases you can manage what data is going to client.

I prefere instead of

> Another possibility is embedding the partial templates on the page itself, but if you're working with a lot of different Partials

working in SPA style and instead partials have a "ViewModel" on Js client.